# Jobs Pagination - Scroll Up on page switch

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, pagination

Title basically says it all. Just a minor feature request.

As of now, if you scroll all the way down at the [Jobs List](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) and click a number on the pagination bar, the site stays at the bottom while the results are refreshed. You then have to manually scroll all the way up again.

I think it's more intuitive, if the pagination on jobs behaves like the one on the normal [StackOverflow Question site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). If you click a page there, the site scrolls up.

If there is a specific reason for this behaviour, please let me know. I'm not sure if other people like this particular functioning, but that's why there's StackOverflow Meta. So I'd love to hear some feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! It was a side-effect of some refactoring I've been doing the last couple of weeks - previously the pagination would reload the entire page whereas now it works AJAXily (in line with the rest of the job search UI). I've tweaked the code so that it now scrolls to the top of the page after the AJAX call completes.